# MySql connector in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, mysql-connector

I try to use MySql Connector for vb.net, But I got the same error always which is

> Can not connect specific host

I use this code :

```
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient
Imports MySql.Data
Imports MySql

Public Class Form1

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    Dim myConnectionString As String

    myConnectionString = "server=example.net;" _
                & "uid=example_support;" _
                & "pwd=passwordhere;" _
                & "database=example_support;"

    Try
        Dim conn As New MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection(myConnectionString)
        conn.Open()
    Catch ex As MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException
        Select Case ex.Number
            Case 0
                MessageBox.Show("Cannot connect to server. Contact administrator")
            Case 1045
                MessageBox.Show("Invalid username/password, please try again")
            Case Else
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        End Select
    End Try


    End Sub
End Class
```

What is possible problem for this error ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error suggests a basic networking issue and not so much a MySQL issue.

I would 1st look to see if the host name is valid and you have basic connectivity (IE from dos prompt can you "ping example.net". It should convert (via DNS) the host name (example.net) to a IP Address (If using IPV4 it will be format nnn.nnn.nnn.nnn where nnn are numbers).

Do you control the host Example.net?
Is there a firewall?
Is the MySQL port open (generally 3306)?

-George